# How do I set value on a slice of dataframe faster?

Tags: python, r, pandas, performance, slice

There is a huge dataframe with hundreds of thousands of rows for every single client. I want to summarise this dataframe into another dataframe where a single row contains the summarised data of all the rows of that client.

The problem is it is not the only code, it contains similar 1000 more lines.
and it takes a lot of time to execute. but when I run this in R. It is 10 times faster. Attaching the R code for reference as well.

Is there a way I can make it fast like R code?

***Python Code:***

```
    for i in range(len(client)):
        print(i)
        
        sub = data.loc[data['Client Name']==client['Client Name'][i],:]
        client['requests'][i] = len(sub)
        client['ppt_req'][i] = len(sub)/sub['CID'].nunique()
    
        client['approval'][i] = (((sub['verify']=='Yes').sum())/client['requests'][i])*100
        client['denial'][i] = (((sub['verify']=='No').sum())/client['requests'][i])*100
    
        client['male'][i] = (((sub['gender']=='Male').sum())/client['requests'][i])*100
        client['female'][i] = (((sub['gender ']=='female').sum())/client['requests'][i])*100
```

***R Code:***

```
for(i in 1: nrow(client))
{print(i)
  #i=1
  sub<-subset(data,data$Client.Name==client$Client.Name[i])
 
  
  client$requests[i]<-nrow(sub)
  client$ppt_req[i]<-nrow(sub)/(length(unique(sub$CID)))
  client$approval[i]<-((as.numeric(table(sub$verify=="Yes")["TRUE"]))/client$requests[i])*100
  
  client$denial[i]<-((as.numeric(table(sub$verify=="No")["TRUE"]))/client$requests[i])*100
  client$male[i]<-((as.numeric(table(sub$gender)["Male"]))/client$requests[i])*100
  client$female[i]<-((as.numeric(table(sub$gender)["Female"]))/client$requests[i])*100
```

Comment: Don't set by loop, you should look into `client.groupby()`.

Comment: The data I am summarizing is in the "data" dataframe, not in the client dataframe. Please suggest how can I use it now?

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over Pandas dataframe using Python loops is very slow.
But the main issue comes from the line `data.loc[data['Client Name']==client['Client Name'][i],:]` which walk through the *whole* dataframe `data` for *each* client. This means this line will finally iterate over >100,000 of strings >100,000 times, and thus **tens of billions of costly string comparisons are made**. Not to mention that per-group computation are replicated for each client.

You can solve this by using a **groupby** on client names followed by a **merge**.
Here is a sketch of code (untested):

```py
# If the number of client name in `data` is much more important than in `client`, 
# one can filter `data` before applying the next `groupby` using:
# client['Client Name'].unique()

# Generate a compact dataframe containing the information for each 
# possible client name that appear in `data`.
clientDataInfos = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'requests': len(group),
        'ppt_req': len(group) / group['CID'].nunique(),
        'approval': (((group['verify']=='Yes').sum()) / len(group)) * 100,
        'denial': (((group['verify']=='No').sum()) / len(group)) * 100,
        'male': (((group['gender']=='Male').sum()) / len(group)) * 100,
        'female': (((group['gender ']=='female').sum()) / len(group)) * 100
    } for name,group in data.groupby('Client Name')
)

# Extend `client` with the precomputed information in `clientDataInfos`.
# The extended columns should not already appear in `client`.
client = client.merge(clientDataInfos, on='Client Name')
```